# Dynamic parsing JSON to Java

Tags: java, json

I have problem with parsing JSON to Java. I have JSON code like that:

```
{
    "Person 1": {
        "name": "Jan",
        "secname": "Kowalski",
        "neighbours": {
            "Person 2": {
                "name": "Pawel",
                "subname": "Nowak"
            },
            "Person 3": {
                "name": "Ewa",
                "subname": "Drzyzga"
            }
        },
        "additionalInformation": {
            "age": "38l",
            "weight": "90kg"
        }
    }
}
```

I have only one Person in a head. He has got name, sec, name, neighbours and additionalInformation. He has 0 or more neigbours, I don't know how many. The same is with additionalInformation. With neighbours is simply because I know that every Person has only name and subname.

So I'm reading neighbours like that:

```
String head = "Person 1";
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
Iterator iterator1 = obj.getJSONObject(head).keys();
while (iterator1.hasNext()) {
    String key = (String) iterator1.next();
    if (key.equals("neighbours")) {
        Iterator iterator2 = obj.getJSONObject(head).getJSONObject(key).keys();
        while (iterator2.hasNext()) {
            String person = (String) iterator2.next();
            System.out.println(obj.getJSONObject(head).getJSONObject(key).getJSONObject(person).getString("name"));
            System.out.println(obj.getJSONObject(head).getJSONObject(key).getJSONObject(person).getString("subname"));
        }
    }
}
```

head can be dynamic, Person 1,2,3... but its not a problem. Problem is with recursive in that json because I don't know how `additionalInformation` will look like. It can be:

```
"additionalInformation ": {
    "parents": {
        "fromDad": {
            "nameM": "Genowefa",
            "nameD": "Jan"
        },
        "fromMother": {
            "nameM": "Krystyna",
            "nameD": "Antoni"
        }
    },
    "weight": "90kg"
}
```

Is that possible to read all information in `"additionalInformation"`?
I have to store data like nodes because if I use method:

```
MODIFY "Person 1" "additionalInformation" "parents" "fromDad" "nameM" "John"
```

`"nameM"` will be change.

Is that possible? Could you tell me something about that?

Comment: What you want to get from additional information

Comment: All information and add to maybe linked list (e.x.) because method `MODIFY "Person 1" "additionalInformation" "parents" "fromDad" "nameM" "John" ` must works. It is TCP Protocole program, that method would be sending from other server to my porogram. There are example data in method, not final.

Comment: Have you considered using something like Jackson for this?

Comment: I found a example where I have to know a key but I don't know what is the name of element